# Checking data in R (whether the full range of values in a data frame column exists)

Tags: r

I have stumbled across a problem in checking data with R. I am fairly new to it and unfortunately, I have not managed to find a solution.

An example of my data frame (let's call it X) is  are as follows:

```
ID     Year       Month
1     2012          7                               
1     2012          8                        
1     2012          9        
2     2012          10                             
1     2012         11        
3     2012         12
```

What I want to do is check for each ID whether all the months from 1 until 12 are present. I have tried this code :

*Dataset_check <- X %>% mutate(check=X$ID<- ifelse(sapply(X$ID, function(Month)
any(X$Month <=12 & X$Month >=1)), "YES", NA))*

but it does not check whether ALL of the months are included but rather if any of the months (1 through 12) are there.

I am not sure which function to use if not "any" to designate that I want to check if all of them exist or not. Do you have any ideas? Am I in the right track at all or should I look at it another way?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(check = if_else(all(1:12 %in% Month), 'Yes','No'))
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   ID [3]
     ID  Year Month check
  <dbl> <dbl> <int> <chr>
1     1  2012     7 No   
2     1  2012     8 No   
3     1  2012     9 No   
4     2  2012    10 No   
5     1  2012    11 No   
6     3  2012    12 No
```

Comment: I just tried it and indeed that worked great! Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

We may use `base R` as well

```
df1$check <-  with(df1, c("No", "Yes")[1 + ave(Month, ID,
      FUN = function(x) all(1:12 %in% x))])
df1$check
[1] "No" "No" "No" "No" "No" "No"
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L), Year = c(2012L, 
2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L), Month = 7:12), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```